# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens: no encuentro el error

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario extenso (76 campos) y no hay manera de localizar el error del número de variables. He generado el código y repasado varias veces y sigo sin ver el problema.

Os paso código por si veis que estoy planteando algo incorrectamente, os paso también foto de phpmyadmin para que veais que son el mismo numero de campos. (ya de paso, ¿existe alguna extensión de vsc que pueda analizar estos casos?)

```
<?php

include('../../../app/config.php');


$nroaccidente_ace = $_POST['nroaccidente_ace'];
$trabajador_ace = $_POST['trabajador_ace'];
$centro_ace = $_POST['centro_ace'];
$lugar_ace = $_POST['lugar_ace'];
$detalleslugar_ace = $_POST['detalleslugar_ace'];
$tipoaccidente_ace = $_POST['tipoaccidente_ace'];
$fecha_ace = $_POST['fecha_ace'];
$fechabaja_ace = $_POST['fechabaja_ace'];
$hora_ace = $_POST['hora_ace'];
$horatrabajo_ace = $_POST['horatrabajo_ace'];
$trabajohabitual_ace = $_POST['trabajohabitual_ace'];
$diadescanso_ace = $_POST['diadescanso_ace'];
$semanadescanso_ace = $_POST['semanadescanso_ace'];
$isevaluadoriesgo_ace = $_POST['isevaluadoriesgo_ace'];
$evalconriesgo_ace = $_POST['evalconriesgo_ace'];
$isrecaida_ace = $_POST['isrecaida_ace'];
$fechaantesrecaida_ace = $_POST['fechaantesrecaida_ace'];
$descripcion_ace = $_POST['descripcion_ace'];
$tipolugar_ace = $_POST['tipolugar_ace'];
$zonalugar_ace = $_POST['zonalugar_ace'];
$observaclugar_ace = $_POST['observaclugar_ace'];
$procesotrabajo_ace = $_POST['procesotrabajo_ace'];
$observproceso_ace = $_POST['observproceso_ace'];
$tipoactividad_ace = $_POST['tipoactividad_ace'];
$observtipoactiv_ace = $_POST['observtipoactiv_ace'];
$agentematerial_ace = $_POST['agentematerial_ace'];
$observagmaterial_ace = $_POST['observagmaterial_ace'];
$desviacion_ace = $_POST['desviacion_ace'];
$observdesviacion_ace = $_POST['observdesviacion_ace'];
$agmaterdesv_ace = $_POST['agmaterdesv_ace'];
$observagendesv_ace = $_POST['observagendesv_ace'];
$formacontacto_ace = $_POST['formacontacto_ace'];
$observformacont_ace = $_POST['observformacont_ace'];
$matercasusalesi_ace = $_POST['matercasusalesi_ace'];
$observmatlesi_ace = $_POST['observmatlesi_ace'];
$numtrafectados_ace = $_POST['numtrafectados_ace'];
$declaraciontrab_ace = $_POST['declaraciontrab_ace'];
$istestigos_ace = $_POST['istestigos_ace'];
$detallestestigo_ace = $_POST['detallestestigo_ace'];
$declaraciontestigo_ace = $_POST['declaraciontestigo_ace'];
$tipolesion_ace = $_POST['tipolesion_ace'];
$gradolesion_ace = $_POST['gradolesion_ace'];
$partecuerpo_ace = $_POST['partecuerpo_ace'];
$isevacuacion_ace = $_POST['isevacuacion_ace'];
$lugarevacuacion_ace = $_POST['lugarevacuacion_ace'];
$centromedico_ace = $_POST['centromedico_ace'];
$detallescentromed_ace = $_POST['detallescentromed_ace'];
$recomedincorp_ace = $_POST['recomedincorp_ace'];
$recinedtrab_ace = $_POST['recinedtrab_ace'];
$istrformado_ace = $_POST['istrformado_ace'];
$istrinformado_ace = $_POST['istrinformado_ace'];
$protcolectivadisp_ace = $_POST['protcolectivadisp_ace'];
$protcolecnecesa_ace = $_POST['protcolecnecesa_ace'];
$observprotcol_ace = $_POST['observprotcol_ace'];
$episdispon_ace = $_POST['episdispon_ace'];
$episneces_ace = $_POST['episneces_ace'];
$observepis_ace = $_POST['observepis_ace'];
$causaaccidente_ace = $_POST['causaaccidente_ace'];
$porquecausa_ace = $_POST['porquecausa_ace'];
$quiencontrolcausa_ace = $_POST['quiencontrolcausa_ace'];
$conclusionacci_ace = $_POST['conclusionacci_ace'];
$medidasprev_ace = $_POST['medidasprev_ace'];
$valoracionmedida_ace = $_POST['valoracionmedida_ace'];
$histaccult12mes_ace = $_POST['histaccult12mes_ace'];
$histpuestoacc_ace = $_POST['histpuestoacc_ace'];
$histtrabajosreal_ace = $_POST['histtrabajosreal_ace'];
$histcausaacc_ace = $_POST['histcausaacc_ace'];
$histmedidaacc_ace = $_POST['histmedidaacc_ace'];
$investigador_ace = $_POST['investigador_ace'];
$cargoinvesiga_ace = $_POST['cargoinvesiga_ace'];
$fechainvestiga_ace = $_POST['fechainvestiga_ace'];
$fechacumplimen_ace = $_POST['fechacumplimen_ace'];
$revisadopor_ace = $_POST['revisadopor_ace'];
$cargorevisado_ace = $_POST['cargorevisado_ace'];
$fecharevision_ace = $_POST['fecharevision_ace'];

$sentencia = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO accidentes (id_accidente,nroaccidente_ace,trabajador_ace,centro_ace,lugar_ace,detalleslugar_ace,tipoaccidente_ace,fecha_ace,fechabaja_ace,hora_ace,horatrabajo_ace,trabajohabitual_ace,diadescanso_ace,semanadescanso_ace,isevaluadoriesgo_ace,evalconriesgo_ace,isrecaida_ace,fechaantesrecaida_ace,descripcion_ace,tipolugar_ace,zonalugar_ace,observaclugar_ace,procesotrabajo_ace,observproceso_ace,tipoactividad_ace,observtipoactiv_ace,agentematerial_ace,observagmaterial_ace,desviacion_ace,observdesviacion_ace,agmaterdesv_ace,observagendesv_ace,formacontacto_ace,observformacont_ace,matercasusalesi_ace,observmatlesi_ace,numtrafectados_ace,declaraciontrab_ace,istestigos_ace,detallestestigo_ace,declaraciontestigo_ace,tipolesion_ace,gradolesion_ace,partecuerpo_ace,isevacuacion_ace,lugarevacuacion_ace,centromedico_ace,detallescentromed_ace,recomedincorp_ace,recinedtrab_ace,istrformado_ace,istrinformado_ace,protcolectivadisp_ace,protcolecnecesa_ace,observprotcol_ace,episdispon_ace,episneces_ace,observepis_ace,causaaccidente_ace,porquecausa_ace,quiencontrolcausa_ace,conclusionacci_ace,medidasprev_ace,valoracionmedida_ace,histaccult12mes_ace,histpuestoacc_ace,histtrabajosreal_ace,histcausaacc_ace,histmedidaacc_ace,investigador_ace,cargoinvesiga_ace,fechainvestiga_ace,fechacumplimen_ace,revisadopor_ace,cargorevisado_ace,fecharevision_ace)
VALUES ( NULL,:nroaccidente_ace,:trabajador_ace,:centro_ace,:lugar_ace,:detalleslugar_ace,:tipoaccidente_ace,:fecha_ace,:fechabaja_ace,:hora_ace,:horatrabajo_ace,:trabajohabitual_ace,:diadescanso_ace,:semanadescanso_ace,:isevaluadoriesgo_ace,:evalconriesgo_ace,:isrecaida_ace,:fechaantesrecaida_ace,:descripcion_ace,:tipolugar_ace,:zonalugar_ace,:observaclugar_ace,:procesotrabajo_ace,:observproceso_ace,:tipoactividad_ace,:observtipoactiv_ace,:agentematerial_ace,:observagmaterial_ace,:desviacion_ace,:observdesviacion_ace,:agmaterdesv_ace,:observagendesv_ace,:formacontacto_ace,:observformacont_ace,:matercasusalesi_ace,:observmatlesi_ace,:numtrafectados_ace,:declaraciontrab_ace,:istestigos_ace,:detallestestigo_ace,:declaraciontestigo_ace,:tipolesion_ace,:gradolesion_ace,:partecuerpo_ace,:isevacuacion_ace,:lugarevacuacion_ace,:centromedico_ace,:detallescentromed_ace,:recomedincorp_ace,:recinedtrab_ace,:istrformado_ace,:istrinformado_ace,:protcolectivadisp_ace,:protcolecnecesa_ace,:observprotcol_ace,:episdispon_ace,:episneces_ace,:observepis_ace,:causaaccidente_ace,:porquecausa_ace,:quiencontrolcausa_ace,:conclusionacci_ace,:medidasprev_ace,:valoracionmedida_ace,:histaccult12mes_ace,:histpuestoacc_ace,:histtrabajosreal_ace,:histcausaacc_ace,:histmedidaacc_ace,:investigador_ace,:cargoinvesiga_ace,:fechainvestiga_ace,:fechacumplimen_ace,:revisadopor_ace,:cargorevisado_ace,:fecharevision_ace)");

$sentencia->bindParam(':id_accidente',$id_accidente);
$sentencia->bindParam(':nroaccidente_ace',$nroaccidente_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':trabajador_ace',$trabajador_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':centro_ace',$centro_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':lugar_ace',$lugar_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':detalleslugar_ace',$detalleslugar_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':tipoaccidente_ace',$tipoaccidente_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':fecha_ace',$fecha_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':fechabaja_ace',$fechabaja_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':hora_ace',$hora_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':horatrabajo_ace',$horatrabajo_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':trabajohabitual_ace',$trabajohabitual_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':diadescanso_ace',$diadescanso_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':semanadescanso_ace',$semanadescanso_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':isevaluadoriesgo_ace',$isevaluadoriesgo_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':evalconriesgo_ace',$evalconriesgo_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':isrecaida_ace',$isrecaida_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':fechaantesrecaida_ace',$fechaantesrecaida_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':descripcion_ace',$descripcion_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':tipolugar_ace',$tipolugar_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':zonalugar_ace',$zonalugar_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':observaclugar_ace',$observaclugar_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':procesotrabajo_ace',$procesotrabajo_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':observproceso_ace',$observproceso_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':tipoactividad_ace',$tipoactividad_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':observtipoactiv_ace',$observtipoactiv_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':agentematerial_ace',$agentematerial_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':observagmaterial_ace',$observagmaterial_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':desviacion_ace',$desviacion_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':observdesviacion_ace',$observdesviacion_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':agmaterdesv_ace',$agmaterdesv_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':observagendesv_ace',$observagendesv_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':formacontacto_ace',$formacontacto_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':observformacont_ace',$observformacont_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':matercasusalesi_ace',$matercasusalesi_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':observmatlesi_ace',$observmatlesi_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':numtrafectados_ace',$numtrafectados_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':declaraciontrab_ace',$declaraciontrab_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':istestigos_ace',$istestigos_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':detallestestigo_ace',$detallestestigo_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':declaraciontestigo_ace',$declaraciontestigo_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':tipolesion_ace',$tipolesion_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':gradolesion_ace',$gradolesion_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':partecuerpo_ace',$partecuerpo_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':isevacuacion_ace',$isevacuacion_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':lugarevacuacion_ace',$lugarevacuacion_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':centromedico_ace',$centromedico_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':detallescentromed_ace',$detallescentromed_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':recomedincorp_ace',$recomedincorp_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':recinedtrab_ace',$recinedtrab_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':istrformado_ace',$istrformado_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':istrinformado_ace',$istrinformado_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':protcolectivadisp_ace',$protcolectivadisp_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':protcolecnecesa_ace',$protcolecnecesa_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':observprotcol_ace',$observprotcol_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':episdispon_ace',$episdispon_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':episneces_ace',$episneces_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':observepis_ace',$observepis_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':causaaccidente_ace',$causaaccidente_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':porquecausa_ace',$porquecausa_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':quiencontrolcausa_ace',$quiencontrolcausa_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':conclusionacci_ace',$conclusionacci_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':medidasprev_ace',$medidasprev_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':valoracionmedida_ace',$valoracionmedida_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':histaccult12mes_ace',$histaccult12mes_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':histpuestoacc_ace',$histpuestoacc_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':histtrabajosreal_ace',$histtrabajosreal_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':histcausaacc_ace',$histcausaacc_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':histmedidaacc_ace',$histmedidaacc_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':investigador_ace',$investigador_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':cargoinvesiga_ace',$cargoinvesiga_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':fechainvestiga_ace',$fechainvestiga_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':fechacumplimen_ace',$fechacumplimen_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':revisadopor_ace',$revisadopor_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':cargorevisado_ace',$cargorevisado_ace);
$sentencia->bindParam(':fecharevision_ace',$fecharevision_ace);


if ($sentencia->execute()) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['mensaje'] = "Actividad registrada correctamente";
    $_SESSION['icono'] = 'success';
    header("Location: " . $URL . "/admin/accidentes");
    } else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['mensaje'] = "Formacion NO creada";
    $_SESSION['icono'] = 'warning';
    header("Location: " . $URL . "/admin/accidentes");
    }
    
    
    ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Pero si estás pasando `NULL` en la primera columna de los `VALUES`...

Comment: paso null por que es el campo clave autoincrementable

Comment: Sí... Pero tenés esto: `$sentencia->bindParam(':id_accidente',$id_accidente);`. ¿Notás el problema?

Comment: gracias, le paso el null a la variable desde arriba

Comment: ese campo no debe ir en el query, independientemente si le pasas null o no, remuevelo, si ya es incrementable en la dB entonces no deberia estar ahi.

Comment: una cosa mas, no se que version de php estes usando pero veo que pones dentro del values(,:) [coma y dos puntos] para separar tus variables, con la pura coma deberia ser suficiente.

Comment: gracias Manny, tomo nota. (demasidado evidente que estoy en proceso de aprendizaje)

Comment: @Manny poner `:` es la manera correcta,  pues se trata de **marcadores de `:nombre`**. Para más detalles [revisa la documentación en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php). Lo demás es como dices en tus comentarios.  Por cada marcador debe haber un valor. Si pasas valores ya puestos en la consulta no tiene sentido poner un marcador para ese valor. El sentido de esto es neutralizar la inyección SQL, la cual se perpetra manipulando los valores precisamente.